# How to not display Leaflet PolyLine Decorator(using marker) on map but layer instead

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working on application uses the leaflet api [Live Here](http://smartminds.cloudapp.net/betaSecurity/)

User must enter "1" in alert input field to use the application.

**Introduction**

Application has some controls to draw different shapes on image.
I am going to discuss one control, which suppose to draw line.

The line actually (polyline) uses leaflet polyline decorator library to decorate the line with some css, nut here i use the marker to display on polyline.

I am using multiple images using different featureGroups.

**Problem**

The line decorator works great, but it shows a strange behaviour as it also draw thos polyline decorator markers on map or map container.
[image: On Top : ImageOverlay, Bottom : map container]

The problem is actually when i draw on image except these polyline decorator marker everything works as desired.

**Script**

```
    var polylinefence4 = new L.Polyline([], { color: 'red' });
    L.easyButton('<img src="/assets/img/fence4.png">', function () {
    }).addTo(map);
    function fencePlace4(e) {
    // Add coordinate to the polyline
     new L.Marker(e.latlng, { icon: fence4Icon, draggable: false }).addTo(currentFeatureGroup);
                        polylinefence4.addLatLng(e.latlng).addTo(currentFeatureGroup);
var decorator = L.polylineDecorator(polylinefence4, {
patterns: [{ offset: 0, repeat: '10px', symbol: new L.Symbol.marker() }]}).addTo(currentFeatureGroup);
                    }
```

I don't know why this is happening, i can't entirely understand the polyline decorator so a bit confusion here.
If someone has knowledge about that problem please do help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Unable to reproduce your problem. The imageoverlay sticks to the map bounds. It would be nice for now and the next time that you precisely describe step by step how and when the problem occurs.

Comment: @iH8 thanks for reply, the given script is actually a custom control...which draws polyline, and as i am using polyline decorator there i have used marker as symbol...when i use "dash or arrow", there is no dash or arrow behind the image on map/map container but when i use marker, then there it displays behind image

Comment: As said i am unable to see behind the image. I tried dragging the image but it flips back to it's original position, covering the entire map. So i am unable to draw outside of the image and when i drag the image, the drawn decorated line moves along with the image. As said unable to reproduce without you giving us the exact precise steps to take to get to this problem.

Comment: @iH8 i am sorry, when you draw some shapes on image, lets say you have drawn some different shapes, then just drag that image (which will flip back)you will see your draw marker

Comment: i mean we draw on image but markers also displays outside of the image, like in screenshot